# Как разложить число на сумму двоек в степени х?

Tags: c#, циклы

Получил задание написать программу представляющую число произвольной длины в виде сумм двоек в степени х.

Например: 545 = 2^9 + 2^5 + 2^0 или 1050  = 2^10 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^1 и т.п.

Не получается прописать цикл для данной операции.

Тип используемой переменной не важен.

Comment: Что значит "не получается цикл"? Вы понимаете, чем вообще является разложение числа на сумму степеней двоек в контексте информатики? Если да, то какие проблемы у вас конкретно? И приведите хоть какой-то код ваших попыток или просто найдите свою задачу на просторах интернета.

Comment: что такое `число произвольной длины` и как вы его хранить собрались в памяти?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Задача является тривиальной в двоичной системе счисления, т.к. в ней каждый разряд это и есть степень двойки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не будем лезть в дебри "числа произвольной длины", представим, что наше число - вполне себе вмещается в Int32.

Допустим мы хотим в десятичной системе выполнить обход каждого разряда, мы просто берём остаток от деления на 10 и делим

```
var num = 1234;
while(num>0)
{
    var digit = num % 10;
    Console.WriteLine(digit);
    num = num / 10;
}
```

Последовательно выведет 4,3,2,1 на отдельных строках.

Можно ещё добавить переменную i, которую последовательно увеличивать на каждой итерации: это будет показатель степени. Для младшего разряда ("единицы") это будет 10 в степени 0, для разряда "десятки" это будет 10 в степени 1, для "сотен" - во второй и так далее:

```
var num = 545;
var i=0;
while(num>0)
{
    var digit = num % 10;
    Console.WriteLine($"i={i} -> {digit}");
    num = num / 10;
    i++;
}
```

Выведет:

> ```
> i=0 -> 5
> i=1 -> 4
> i=2 -> 5
> ```

В двоичной системе мы можем провернуть абсолютно по аналогии:

```
var num = 545;
var i=0;
while(num>0)
{
    var digit = num & 1;
    Console.WriteLine($"i={i} -> {digit}");
    num = num >> 1;
    i++;
}
```

Если вам не знакома битовая арифметика - то это тоже самое, что и:

```
var num = 545;
var i=0;
while(num>0)
{
    var digit = num % 2;
    Console.WriteLine($"i={i} -> {digit}");
    num = num / 2;
    i++;
}
```

Оба варианта выведут на экран:

> ```
> i=0 -> 1
> i=1 -> 0
> i=2 -> 0
> i=3 -> 0
> i=4 -> 0
> i=5 -> 1
> i=6 -> 0
> i=7 -> 0
> i=8 -> 0
> i=9 -> 1
> ```

(Узнаёте число на экране калькулятора?)

Так что ваш исходный алгоритм - это просто пропускать нолики, а для единичек добавлять в вывод строку `+ 2 ^ i`:

```
var list = new List<string>();
var num = 545;
var i=0;
while(num>0)
{
    var digit = num & 1;
    if(digit == 1)
        list.Add($"2^{i}");
    //Console.WriteLine($"i={i} -> {digit}");
    num = num >> 1;
    i++;
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("+", list));
```

На выходе получим: 2^0+2^5+2^9 (можете сделать реверс списка, если вам нужен порядок "от старшего разряда к младшему)

Аналогичный подход будет и для "чисел произвольной длины", чтобы это ни значило.

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections;

string s = "13124214345345395634756835634753583457834575837345734";
BigInteger bigint = BigInteger.Parse(s);
BitArray ba = new BitArray(bigint.ToByteArray());

List<string> ls = new List<string>();
BigInteger check = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++)
{
    if (ba[i] == true)
    {
        check += new BigInteger(Math.Pow(2, i));
        ls.Add($"2^{i}");
    }
}
WriteLine(check); //проверяем: 13124214345345395634756835634753583457834575837345734
ls.Reverse();
string result = check.ToString() + " = " + String.Join(" + ", ls);
WriteLine(result);
```

Получаем вывод:
`13124214345345395634756835634753583457834575837345734 = 2^173 + 2^169 + 2^168 + 2^164 + 2^161 + 2^160 + 2^159 + 2^158 + 2^157 + 2^156 + 2^153 + 2^152 + 2^151 + 2^149 + 2^147 + 2^146 + 2^144 + 2^139 + 2^137 + 2^136 + 2^132 + 2^129 + 2^128 + 2^127 + 2^126 + 2^124 + 2^123 + 2^119 + 2^118 + 2^117 + 2^112 + 2^110 + 2^108 + 2^105 + 2^102 + 2^99 + 2^96 + 2^95 + 2^94 + 2^93 + 2^91 + 2^89 + 2^88 + 2^86 + 2^85 + 2^84 + 2^83 + 2^82 + 2^81 + 2^80 + 2^77 + 2^75 + 2^72 + 2^70 + 2^68 + 2^66 + 2^65 + 2^63 + 2^61 + 2^59 + 2^58 + 2^57 + 2^56 + 2^55 + 2^54 + 2^52 + 2^47 + 2^45 + 2^41 + 2^37 + 2^34 + 2^33 + 2^32 + 2^30 + 2^29 + 2^28 + 2^26 + 2^25 + 2^19 + 2^16 + 2^13 + 2^12 + 2^10 + 2^9 + 2^8 + 2^7 + 2^6 + 2^2 + 2^1`

Или если на входе: s = "545";
На выходе: 545 = 2^9 + 2^5 + 2^0